# Convert grid coordinates to world and back

Tags: function, math, formula, projection

I have a 2D grid with tiles and I place them in my game world like this:
[image]

```
public static Vector2 IndexToWorldPosition(int mapX, int mapY, float tileWidth, float tileHeight)
{
    float x = (mapX - mapY) * tileWidth / 2f;
    float y = (mapX + mapY) * tileHeight / 2f;
    return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

Tile width and height are 1 and 0.5 world units. The layout works as expected and gives me the typical diamond shape. Now I want to reverse the function and get the correct map indices from a world position (e.g. the mouse converted to world space).

```
public static IntVector2 WorldPositionToIndex(Vector2 mouseWorld, float tileWidth, float tileHeight)
{
    float x = mouseWorld.x / tileWidth + mouseWorld.y / tileHeight;
    float y = mouseWorld.y / tileHeight - mouseWorld.x / tileWidth;
    return new IntVector2(Mathf.FloorToInt(x), Mathf.FloorToInt(y));
}
```

The second function appears to be wrong. When testing, only world positions close the grid origin report correct indices, everything further away gets increasingly inaccurate, but I can't seem to find out what the problem is. I've also tried to replace *FloorToInt* with *Ceil* and *Round*, but it only increased or decreased the already incorrect offset. Also, I have made sure that the reported world mouse position is correct. I've also written a unit tests with fixed input and expected output values, and it reports, that the second function does in fact not inverse the first one correctly.

Can anyone spot the mistake or point me in the right direction how to correctly invert the first function?

Addition: Here are my unit tests for both functions:

```
[TestCase(0, 0, 0, 0)]
[TestCase(0, 1, -0.5f, -0.25f)]
[TestCase(0, 2, -1f, -0.5f)]
[TestCase(1, 0, 0.5f, -0.25f)]
[TestCase(1, 1, 0f, -0.5f)]
[TestCase(1, 2, -0.5f, -0.75f)]
[TestCase(2, 0, 1f, -0.5f)]
[TestCase(2, 1, 0.5f, -0.75f)]
[TestCase(2, 2, 0f, -1f)]
public void Conversion_Works(int mapX, int mapY, float expectedX, float expectedY)
{
    UnityEngine.Vector2 result = DimetricLayout.CoordinateToWorldPosition(mapX, mapY, 1f, 0.5f);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedX, result.x);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedY, result.y);
}

[TestCase(0, 0, 0, 0)]
[TestCase(0, 1, -0.5f, -0.25f)]
[TestCase(0, 2, -1f, -0.5f)]
[TestCase(1, 0, 0.5f, -0.25f)]
[TestCase(1, 1, 0f, -0.5f)]
[TestCase(1, 2, -0.5f, -0.75f)]
[TestCase(2, 0, 1f, -0.5f)]
[TestCase(2, 1, 0.5f, -0.75f)]
[TestCase(2, 2, 0f, -1f)]
public void Conversion_Mouse(int expectedX, int expectedY, float mouseX, float mouseY)
{
    IntVector2 result = DimetricLayout.WorldPositionToCoordinate(new UnityEngine.Vector2(mouseX, mouseY), 1f, 0.5f);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedX, result.x);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedY, result.y);
}
```

Comment: The function looks good to me. Can you provide the example fixed input and expect output values from your unit test that fails?

Comment: And there I go finding my problem: While running my unit tests, I had flipped one of the axis, but forgot the other one while experimenting, so the tests reported as failed, while visually I was getting incorrect values because of the incorrect pivot point of my sprites. After setting the pivot to the bottom corner, everything worked correctly and my tests were correct all along.